# Digital communications - Gold code sequences

Tags: digital-communications

What other properties does Gold code sequences have besides having a limited cross-correlation property?

Answer (score 0):

Several, due to their being generated from m sequences.

For instance, they are easy to generate with hardware or software.

For other properties see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_code)